# Firefox Fixed Position Doesn't Animate

Tags: css, firefox, jquery-animate, css-transitions, css-animations

Here is a simple example of my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/b700ja5a/1/

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="runTest" value="Run Test" />
<div id="fixPosTest">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#fixPosTest {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 40%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
    z-index: 100;
    transition:left 1s linear;
}

#fixPosTest .inner {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff99ff;
  z-index: 110;
}
```

JS (jQuery)

```
$('#runTest').on('click', function() {
    $('#fixPosTest').css({left: '50%'});
});
```

In Chrome PC 48 the pink box animates smoothly within the red frame. In Firefox PC 44 the pink box gets left behind until something triggers a repaint. Firefox has the same problem if I have jQuery do the animation instead of CSS.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Bugzilla tracking here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1248727